# python read a value from object

Tags: python

I am trying to read a value from an object, but I am getting a error:

My object:

```
data = {"test"}
```

My code:

```
data.values()
```

Error:
`has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: `{"test"}` is a set. Why do you have this one-element set in the first place?

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `data = set(["test"])` - hope that helps :-)

Comment: also, you are probably looking for `list(data)[0]` or even `next(iter(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data = {"test"}` is a set, not a dictionary, so you could try:

```
print(list(data))
```

Or:

```
print([*data])
```

Both output:

```
['test']
```

Answer (score 0):

At least you need to do:

```
data = {'test': 'my value'}
```